# Can't create FAT32 partition with gpart under FreeBSD

Tags: partition, freebsd

Gpart (not gparted) under FreeBSD has problems to add a FAT32 partition when using GPT (works with MBR).

This is the disk:

```
% gpart show /dev/da0
=>      40  15257520  da0  GPT  (7.3G)
        40  15257520       - free -  (7.3G)
```

But now I get an error:

```
% gpart add -t fat32 /dev/da0
gpart: Invalid argument
```

How do I create a FAT32 partition with a GUID Partition Table under FreeBSD?

Comment: Does it work if you create an exFAT filesystem?

Answer (score 7):

`man gpart`, section `PARTITION TYPES` states:

```
ms-basic-data               A basic data partition (BDP) for Microsoft
                            operating systems.  In the GPT this type is
                            the equivalent to partition types fat16, fat32
                            and ntfs in MBR.
```

So, since you are using `GPT` scheme, you have to use `ms-basic-data` type instead of `fat32`.